# Insert sequence value in a column within the scope of a foreign key - Rails and Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, schema

I would like to have a column in my table which auto_increements within the scope of a foreign key.

```
   id   |   foreign_key_column   |   this_column_i_want
--------------------------------------------------------
   1    |         1              |           1
   2    |         1              |           2   
   3    |         1              |           3
   4    |         2              |           1
   5    |         2              |           2
   6    |         3              |           1
```

Is this kind of schema possible through rails migrations?

Consider the scenario below:
This table represents **Orders** table.
If this table stores orders from multiple stores, then the foreign key column would be **store_id**. Now, the different stores need their invoices to be sequential within their scope. Earlier the invoices were globally sequential.

So every store's invoice number must start at 1, and keep in increasing based on the records created for that particular store.

Hope this helps to explain the question.

Comment: You can create [DB triggers in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html) to do pretty much anything. There is no built in support for this in rails migrations but using raw SQL in a migration is possible.

Comment: I thought this [gem](https://github.com/derrickreimer/sequenced) may help you

Comment: @fongfan999 I think you could add that as an answer.  It solves the OP's problem exactly.

Comment: @WayneConrad, Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a gem called [sequenced](https://github.com/derrickreimer/sequenced). I thought it will solve your problem.

> Sequenced is a simple gem that generates scoped sequential IDs for
>   ActiveRecord models. This gem provides an acts_as_sequenced macro that
>   automatically assigns a unique, sequential ID to each record. The
>   sequential ID is not a replacement for the database primary key, but
>   rather adds another way to retrieve the object without exposing the
>   primary key.

---

The gem provides a Ruby/Rails implementation. It used [ActiveModel::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) to set the value of `sequential_id` column: `before_save :set_sequential_ids` [[link]](https://github.com/derrickreimer/sequenced/blob/master/lib/sequenced/acts_as_sequenced.rb#L48).

```
def acts_as_sequenced(options = {})
  # ...
  include Sequenced::ActsAsSequenced::InstanceMethods

  mattr_accessor :sequenced_options, instance_accessor: false

  self.sequenced_options = []

  before_save :set_sequential_ids
  # ...
end
```

Here is the setter method [[link]](https://github.com/derrickreimer/sequenced/blob/master/lib/sequenced/generator.rb#L13):

```
def set
  return if id_set? || skip?
  lock_table
  record.send(:"#{column}=", next_id)
end
```

Comment: Could you please let me know if this gem provides a DB implementation or a Ruby one? The answer is closest to what I need to achieve, but having some more information around it would be great.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I've just updated my answer. Please have a look :)

Comment: I only briefly looked at the gem but noticed it acquires an exclusive table lock, which feels ... risky ... if your table has high write throughput. As far as I understand it, reads would still be allowed